# Laravel use controller based on user progress in game

Tags: php, laravel, controller

In my current application users can play a game. The game consists of 5 steps. I use a model UserProgress to log the user's progress. Depending on the current next step the user has to do some actions.

Currently I have one controller and one function which does the orchestration of all the steps, which is bad.

However I would like to have a function per step of the game as this is more clear. However the URL for each step should be the same.

I'm not too sure what the best practice is to do the orchestration? Should it be done in routing or should I create another function in my controller which deals with the orchestration?

Thanks in advance for your tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you did not provide any of your code I can only give you a basic concert.

1) I assume you use a POST request if the user submits a status/page. Off course a get request is also possible but you save data in your DB so I would use a POST request.

2) So on each request you add a parameter indicating the step, this can be a additional Query String like `?step=<nr>` or one additional POST parameter from a hidden input field:
`<input type="hidden" name="step" value="<nr>">`

3) You route will hand over all request to your public controller function

```
public function nextStep(Request $request)
{
     switch ($request->get('step'))
     {
         case 1: return $this->stepOne($request);
         case 2: return $this->stepTwo($request);
         case 3: return $this->stepThree($request);
         case 4: return $this->stepFour($request);
     }
}

protected function stepOne(Request $request)
{
    // To Step One
    return view(step_two);
}

protected function stepTwo(Request $request)
{
    // To Step Two
    return view(step_tree);
}

protected function stepThree(Request $request)
{
    // To Step Three
    return view(step_four);
}

protected function stepFour(Request $request)
{
    // To Step Four
    return view(step_final);
}
```